# Керниган, Ритчи. Задача: Напишите программу, печатающую гистограммы длин вводимых слов

Tags: c

Помогите разобраться. При выполнении консоль виснет и не отвечает на команды. В интернете нашел только варианты решений, которые предполагают в гистограмме показ того, насколько часто встречаются слова заданных длин. Я же хочу для тренировки показать на гистограмме длину каждого отдельного слова, по сути заменив каждый символ чертой, но консоль после первого перехода на новую строку зависает, как будто все зациклилось.

```
#define OUT 0  // внутри слова
#define IN 1   // вне слова
#define WORDNUM 10  // номер слова

int main()
{
    int sym, state, i, j;
    state = OUT;
    int wlengths[WORDNUM]; // длины слов
    for (i = 0;i < WORDNUM;++i)
        wlengths[i] = 0;
    while ((sym = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < WORDNUM;)
        {
            if ((sym == ' ' || sym == '\n' || sym == '\t') && (state == IN))
            {
                state = OUT;
                ++i;
            }
            else if (sym == ' ' || sym == '\n' || sym == '\t');
            else 
            {
                state = IN;
                ++wlengths[i];
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0;i < WORDNUM;++i)
    {
        printf("|%d|", i);
        for (j = wlengths[i]; j > 0; --j)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте для тренировки посмотреть, что попадает в wlengths

Comment: В wlengths я по идее складываю длину текущего слова, пока символ-разделитель не переведет на следующий элемент массива, в котором будет длина следующего слова

Comment: Бывает так, что идея отличается от того, что на самом деле.

Comment: Так и не смог понять, что именно не так с wlengths. Я же инкрементирую нулевое значение элемента при каждом символе не разделителе, а на разделителе перехожу на следующее слово. Возможно, я не знаю каких-то тонкостей.

Comment: Я не утверждаю, что там что-то не то. Я предложил убедиться, что там действительно находится, что вы думаете. Напечатать значения, например. А то бывает думаешь одно, а на самом деле происходит другое.